# How to add code to an inherited function?

Tags: python

I know this is stupid, but I don't know. I can't figure out method as decorator. I have 2 classes: 1 Button and 1 child Button. I want to play a sound when the button is clicked. So there is a **call** function in the Button class.

```
class Button:
    def __call__(self):
        print("play")
```

Now in the child class, I want the button to do something, but I still want to play the sound. If I override the **call** function, the play sound part will disappear.

```
class ChildButtonn(Button):
    def __call__(self):
        # button things but the sound is gone
        # I need to write the play thing again here
        print("play")
```

So how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the parent class' `__call__` method:

```
class ChildButtonn(Button):
    def __call__(self):
        super().__call__()
        print("specific actions for ChildButtonn")
        ...
```

FWIW, are you sure you need to use `__call__`? unless dealing with a very specific requirement (eg when using the object as a callable callback), using `__call__` usually end up with unreadable code (who knows what `ChildButtonn()()` might or might not do?). It is usually better to use a named method, eg `ChildButtonn().click()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ChildButtonn(Button):
    def __call__(self):
        # button things but the sound is gone
        # I need to write the play thing again here
        super().__call__() #will __call__ parent class method
```

You can use 'super' to use parent class.

Answer (score 1):

call the parent class `__call__` inside the `ChildButton`'s `__call__` function using `super` function

```
class Button:
    def __call__(self):
        print("play")

class ChildButtonn(Button):
    def __call__(self):
        super().__call__()
        print("play")


c = ChildButtonn()
c()
```